# CakePHP redirect to another url but same controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I am starting with cake php and mvc and php frameworks, so I am a bit confused.

As I saw cakephp allows me to route the urls, so I have a Users controller for administration and I want to know How can I redirect it to /admin/users/* instead of /users/*.

I have tried this:

```
Router::connect('/admin/users', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
```

But this makes the controller to be on /users also, I want that the /users url dissapear and instead use /admin/users.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use [Prefix Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)?

Comment: It is good. But the /users route continues staying there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. I finally managed it by using the prefix routes and throwing a notfoundexception in the index of the users controller. This makes the /users dissapear.

Answer (score 2):

To Preserve cake routes 
include:-

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

in end of file, after your routes.

Answer (score 1):

Your route is correct. But to deactivate the "/users" route, you need to remove default cakephp routes. Delete the following line in routes.php:

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

More information here => http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#disabling-the-default-routes

Comment: Will this remove the routes that cakephp creates for me?

Comment: Yes. But this is what you want to do by removing the default /users route, no?

Comment: But I want to preserve all my others routes, like /contact